# Angular Expansion panel not opening

Tags: angular, panel, angular-components, expansion

hey guys can anyone help me i tried a lot but don't know why it is not working....
what is happening is, when i am opening expansion panel Programmatically then it is open sometime and sometime not.
when i do a ctrl+shift+R then its work fine. but when i close the panel and navigate again to that component then it doesnt work. but the toggle shows its expensded (You can see in red highlighted)

[See image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwCdR.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwCdR.png)

what i am doing is when expansion panel have data then i set  ingredientsExpansion to true.

```
 headPanleToggle(){
this.ingredientsExpansion=true; //head panel Toggle
```

}

<mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="ingredientsExpansion">

but the pannel is not opening afer seeting it true

see below image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJtMu.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJtMu.png)

Comment: Create reproduceable example

Comment: Please give more details on the issue.

Comment: see this : a live example given with full code https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview

 u must install angular material first

Comment: @frost  can you see the image i have uploaded... expended is set true but still it is not opened

Comment: Put code for us to check... with just images we can't help you. The problem for sure is somewhere else and not on the angular component. Be aware that the  OPs might close this ticket as "insufficient research".

Comment: @Manu if you can't give real project code, please try to make a fake project only for ur component where your exp. panel is located. We need to understand your .ts to tell more about it

Answer (score 0):

**.html:**

```
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel hideToggle>
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        This is the expansion title
      </mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-description>
        This is a summary of the content
      </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <p>This is the primary content of the panel.</p>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
  <mat-expansion-panel (opened)="panelOpenState = true"
                       (closed)="panelOpenState = false">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        Self aware panel
      </mat-panel-title>
      <mat-panel-description>
        Currently I am {{panelOpenState ? 'open' : 'closed'}}
      </mat-panel-description>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <p>I'm visible because I am open</p>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

**.ts :**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

/**
 * @title Basic expansion panel
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'expansion-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'expansion-overview-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['expansion-overview-example.css'],
})
export class ExpansionOverviewExample {
  panelOpenState = false;
}
```

.css:

```
.mat-form-field + .mat-form-field {
  margin-left: 8px;
}
```

See ? I don't need to make a open/close by function.

But If you must - See that line in my .ts

```
  panelOpenState = false;
```

just make it true or false by your function. I guess only setting this boolean should be enough

Comment: it's not working panel is not opening when i set panelOpenState=true

Comment: @Manu when you can solve it, please post an answer here. We want to know